# Rewriting linear code representation (coding theory).

Tags: modular-arithmetic, information-theory, coding-theory

**Linear codes:** In coding theory, we have a linear codes where a ***message*** is passed through an ***encoder*** to get a ***code***. A linear code is the situation where a message $u=(u_1,\dots,u_k)\in\{0,1\}^k$ (notice that this is a row vector) is passed through a linear encoder to give $x=uG\,(\text{mod 2})\in\{0,1\}^n$ where (mod 2) just means that operations are done in modulo-2 arithmetic and $G\in\{0,1\}^{k\times n}$ here is the encoding matrix.

**Question:** Can I rewrite the above setup such that I get the following:

- I no longer need the requirement for operations to be done in modulo-2 arithmetic, just normal arithmetic that we are used to (i.e., no need to take remainders etc).
- Entries of $x$ are in $\{-1,+1\}$ instead of $\{0,1\}$.
  Can this be done through redefining how we represent $u$ and $G$, and by using some other mathematical function?
- You are allowed to write $x=f(uG)$, where $f(\cdot)$ is a function (that applies element wise to the vector) up to your choosing, except those that involve floor and ceiling functions. Otherwise, we can write $x_i=\boldsymbol{1}\{\lceil uG_j/2\rceil=\lfloor uG_j/2 \rfloor+1\}$, where $G_j$ is the $j$th column of $G$.
- Essentially, you are free to do anything as long as the modulo-2 arithmetic can be removed.

**Attempt:** I was thinking maybe to keep $G\in\{0,1\}^{k\times n}$ and change the entries of $u$ to be in $\{-1,+1\}$ with $0$ being mapped to $-1$, and $1$ being mapped to $+1$. Then we can have $x=\text{sign}(uG)$, where $\text{sign}(\cdot)$ is defined as
\begin{align*}
\text{sign}(\theta)=
\begin{cases}
+1 \text{ if $\theta\geq0$}\\
-1 \text{ otherwise.}\\
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
and applied element wise to the vector $uG$. But on further thought this is wrong. I am wondering if I can do something similar to get my goal...

**Motivation:** I am just curious if the linear coding model can be represented as something similar to that of compressed sensing (or specifically one-bit compressed sensing) -- without the need for the nasty modulo-2 arithmetic. Thanks for the help.

Comment: It is not really clear what you aim to achieve. Modulo-2 arithmetic yields values in $\{0,1\}$, i.e., bits, and it essentially generalizes what in practice is done with binary $u$, $G$ and Boolean algebra. In other words, depending on your choice of alphabet and code, there are likely easier methods to obtain the encoded message than using modulo arithmetic.
One way to make the code _essentially_ different is to use an alphabet of $m>2$ symbols, but again, the modulo-$m$ operation generalizes whatever design one might devise.

Comment: Yes, I want to rewrite the model that currently uses modulo-2 arithmetic but without using modulo-2 arithmetic. So I want to rewrite it to look like a compressed sensing model so that I can use known decoders for compressed sensing to solve this linear coding problem (i.e., recover the message).

Comment: So, I want to know what choice of alphabet and code gives me an encoded message that is in $\{-1,+1\}^n$. Can you give me a specific choice that avoids using any modulo arithmetic? Thanks. Something along the lines of my attempt (written above) would be the best.

Comment: modulo-2 arithmetic is not "nasty". Actually linear codes (which are more general, they are not necessarily binary) use Galois fields, which have all (or most) of the nice properties of "standard" arithmetic. In the particular case of binary codes, they use GF(2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mapping $a\rightarrow (-1)^a$ is indeed used in coding and sequence design applied to vectors. This gives the pleasing property that if two vectors $x,y \in \{0,1\}^n$ satisfy $d(x,y)=n/2,$ assuming $n$ even, we get two orthogonal vectors $u,v$ if we define
$$
u=(u_i)_i^n\quad \mathrm{ with }\quad u_i=(-1)^{x_i},\quad 
v=(v_i)_i^n\quad \mathrm{ with }\quad v_i=(-1)^{y_i}.
$$

However, the $GF(2)$ based algebraic theory of code generation via with parity check and generator matrices does not have a straightforward conversion to a space of real and more generally complex linear algebra. The crucial part is that we have finite arithmetic in $GF(2)$ or other finite fields.

Once noise is added to the picture (after converting to the $\{\pm 1\}$ alphabet then the continuous point of view is more helpful, with probability also playing a major part.

A nice book that covers this area with lots of applications is Schroeder, M. R. (2009). *Number theory in science and communication : with applications in cryptography, physics, digital information, computing, and self-similarity* Springer Verlag.